# WSO2 Start - up (Sending Simple Message)

Tags: wso2

Hello I would like to ask why I am getting the following error when I follow the start up samples for WSO2 ESB 5.0.0:

Exception occurred :Illegal character in path at index 12: /healthcare/{uri.var.category}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

I obtain the error from the Commandline (I am using windows), when I do the curl command (curl -v http://localhost:8280/healthcare/querydoctor/surgery)

How can I sol0ve the prolem? Thanks

Comment: Which sample are you trying out?

Comment: Can you post the xml for the endpoint and for the API?