# WSO2 ESB Tutorial Error

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I found the exact same problem here but there was no answer, and I can't move on with this without an answer.

[WSO2 Start - up (Sending Simple Message)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186597/wso2-start-up-sending-simple-message)

The sample I'm trying to use is hosted in WSO2 App Cloud at http://wso2training-restsamples.wso2apps.com, and the tutorial is this one: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sending+a+Simple+Message

As far as I know I followed the tutorial to the letter, but when I get to sending the GET request, although it logs in the Eclipse console, on my console, after doing this command:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8280/healthcare/querydoctor/surgery
```

I get this

```
Exception occurred :Illegal character in path at index 12: /healthcare/{uri.var.category}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

HealthCareAPI.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/healthcare" name="HealthcareAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/querydoctor/{category}">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="Request Log" level="custom">
                <property name="message" value="&quot;Welcome to HealthcareService&quot;"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="QueryDoctorEP"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

QueryDoctorEP.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="QueryDoctorEP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="get" uri-template="http://wso2training-restsamples.wso2apps.com/healthcare/{uri.var.category} "/>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: Can you provide the xml for the HealthCareAPI in your project?

Comment: And the endpoint xml as well

Comment: @RodrigoVasconcelos added to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo (an extra space at the end) in your endpoint `url-template`. Be careful not to include whitespaces in the beggining or end of your templates.

```
uri-template="http://wso2training-restsamples.wso2apps.com/healthcare/{uri.var.category}"
```

Remove it and ou should get the expected output.

Comment: Wow, did not see that and wasn't even expecting it to be something that simple, thank you!